# Move files into folders if any one word identical in name

Tags: batch-file, filenames, directory

I want move this files (extension is irrilevant)

```
cane pazzo.txt
cane.torrent
incredibile cane s03.xx
```

into folder

```
cane
```

I have this code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            move %%a %%b
        )
    )
)
popd
```

but I can move only files that have the same name as the folder

```
cane.torrent --> cane
```

Instead these files

```
cane pazzo.txt
incredibile cane s03.xx
```

are not moved inside because have more of one word inside filename. Why??

Any solution with .bat script?

Comment: In PowerShell it would be `foreach ($dir in gci -Directory) { gci | where Name -match $dir.Name | mv -Destination $dir }`

Comment: So the folder `cane` exists already, and its name is the word to search for in the file names?

Comment: @aschipfl
Yes, it is correctly..but I don't know how I must use powershell. I copy command but it tell me invalid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct. The only point is that `move` command should enclose the file in quotes, so names that include spaces be processed correctly:

```
move "%%a" "%%b"
```

I also would eliminate the "x" in the comparison, because it is not necessary:

```
if NOT "!_file:%%b=!" == "!_file!" (
```